# ag-grid hidden columns visible after row grouping changed

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have the following issue with setting row groups and hidden columns.

Initially when I fetch the column definitions I set the row groups like below

```
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnsAndData[0]);
this.gridOptions.columnApi.setRowGroupColumns(this.selectedGroupBy);     / selectedGroupBy is string[]
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(columnsAndData[1]);
```

This works fine and any hidden columns in columnDefs are not showing on the grid.

Subsequently when I change the row grouping via below method the hidden columns become visible.

```
changeGroupBy(): void {
this.gridOptions.columnApi.setRowGroupColumns(this.selectedGroupBy);
this.gridOptions.api.refreshGroupRows(); }
```

Can you explain this behaviour and why hidden columns are reset to visible again?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently adding a flag to the gridOptions fixes this issue
suppressMakeColumnVisibleAfterUnGroup

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping